# Issue with finding minimum value of array

Tags: java, arrays

I am having a slight issue when finding the minimum value of my random array. I keep getting 0 as a result for the smallest number. Largest number would appear to be fine. I also receive the wrong number for the index of both as well.

Current Code:

```
public class RandomArray {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int indexHigh = 0;
    int indexLow = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;

    int[] randArray = new int[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++)
    {
        randArray[i] = RandomMethod.randomInt(1,1000);
        System.out.print(randArray[i] + " ");
        System.out.println(" ");

        //Max & Min
         if (randArray[i] > max)
          max = randArray[i];
         indexHigh = i;
            if (randArray[i] < min)
                min = randArray[i];
         indexLow =  i;
    }

            System.out.println("The highest minimum for the December is: " + min + " at index: " + indexLow);
            System.out.println("The highest maximum for the December is: " + max + " at index: " + indexHigh);


    }

}
```

Supporting Class(Instructions stated that it needed to be in another class. Only the method is necessary):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.*;

public class RandomMethod {

    //implement random class
    static Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        //#7 -- Generates a number between 10 & 20 ( 100x )

        /*
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter <= 100)
        {
            System.out.println(randomInt(10,20));
            counter++;
        }
        */

        //# 8

        //int[] randArray = new int[randomInt(1,1000)];


    }


    // Random Int method where value is greater than x & less than y
    public static int randomInt(int x, int y)
    {
        int randomValue = randomNumbers.nextInt(y - x) + x;
        return randomValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: `min` starts at zero and all the elements in the array are greater than `1`. All numbers will thus be larger than `min` and your `min` will never be updated. You should set the starting value of `min` to either the first element of the array, or some very large value that you know is larger than all the elements in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I keep getting 0 as a result for the smallest number

That's because you have initialized `min = 0`. And your `randInt()` will never generate a number `< 0`. So your `min` will never change.

**To Fix**, have the initial `min` to be higher than the highest your randInt will generate.

```
int min = 1001; // Or to be safer, use Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

> I also receive the wrong number for the index of both as well.

That's because your `if` statement doesn't include `indexHigh = i;` statement.

Use,

```
 if (randArray[i] > max) {
  max = randArray[i];
  indexHigh = i;
 }
    if (randArray[i] < min) {
        min = randArray[i];
        indexLow =  i;
 }
```

Comment: Kudos, I always seem to fall for the same mistakes on every project.

Answer (score 2):

You min is initialized to `0` already. So it's only looking for the smallest value below zero. Initialize min to a higher number, higher than what the expected input will be, or use `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`.

For index printing, it's a matter of braces `{}` for the if statements. What happens right now is that on every loop, `indexHigh` & `indexLow` are reset with the value of `i`.

```
     //Max & Min
     if (randArray[i] > max){
       max = randArray[i];
       indexHigh = i;
     }
     if (randArray[i] < min){
       min = randArray[i];
       indexLow =  i;
     }
```

This way, those two variables only take the value of `i` upon actually encountering a higher/lower value.

Answer (score 0):

The variable to check he minimum value should be initialized with big number. Try

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```